# how to get python 3 to act on commands from text.txt

Tags: python-3.x, turtle-graphics, directions

I have two files and I need turtle_directions.py to read off the directions in test.txt. I have been trying to work on this but it just won't read and act on my commands, any help would be much appreciated.

```
import turtle

window = turtle.Screen()
spoc = turtle.Turtle()

def line():
    contents = []
    with open('test.txt') as f:
        for line in f:
            row = line.split()
            contents.append(row)
            print(contents)

line()

window.exitonclick()
```

The text file I'm trying to get this program to read is test.txt

```
pendown
color gold 
goto 50 50 
goto 50 100
circle 10
```

Any help would be MUCH appriciated, I've been stuck on this since yesterday

EDIT: I have the commands in the list it just thinks they are strings instead of commands :/

Answer (score 0):

The 'commands' in text.txt are not proper Python syntax.  You have to either use proper Python syntax and exec the code, or write your own interpreter.  I presume you want to do the former.  The command will have to be the same as if they were in the file itself, or entered interactively.

For the purpose of testing, it is easier to put the text as a multiline string in the same file.  You can later add text = file.read().  The following, with the two changes indicated, works.

```
import turtle as t
window = t.Screen()

text = '''
t.pendown()
t.color('gold')
t.goto(50, 50)
t.goto(50, 100)
t.circle(10)
'''

exec(text)
```

Just one warning: do not use exec() with code you did not write yourself or do not trust.